# Intellij integrated terminal font ligatures zsh

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, fonts, zsh, iterm2

IntelliJ's integrated terminal doesn't seem to work with font ligatures. Zsh works and gets the correct theme but the built in terminal doesn't use the correct font. (see screenshot below)

Ligatures work fine in iTerm2 and the editor section of IntellJ using fira code font.

Attempts so far:

- I've set the shell path under `Preferences/Tools/Terminal` to  `/bin/zsh`
- Enabled font ligatures and set font to fira code under `Editor/Font`
- Enabled font ligatures set font to fira code under `Editor/Color Scheme/Console Font`

[image]

Comment: This is a terminal issue (with font rendering), not a shell issue.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I thought it could have been a combination of both which is why I added the extra info about zsh. Either way Jetbrains seem to know about it. See the link in CrazyCoder’s answer for their progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217500). You can [follow](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) it for updates.

Comment: Thank you, guess it's a waiting game then.